# Generating news from db table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to generate news from db table.

My table look like that

[image]

And the function that generated news from db table

```
function generateNews ($lang, $db)
{
    $title = 'title_' . $lang;
    $short = 'short_' . $lang;
    $detailed = 'detailed_' . $lang;
    $result=$db->query("SELECT id, $title as title, $short as short, $detailed as detailed, ndate FROM news");

    while($row=$result->fetch_object()) {
        $title=makeEntry ('title', $row->title);
        $stitle=makeEntry ('stitle', $row->short);
        $content=makeEntry ('content',$row->detailed);
        $footer=makeEntry ('footer',$row->ndate);

        echo makeEntry ('entry',$title.$stitle.$content.$footer);
    }   
}   

function makeEntry ($part,$data)
{
    if($part=='title')
        return '<h3 class="entry-header">'.$data.'</h3>'."\n";
    else if ($part=='stitle')
        return '<h4 class="entry-stitle">'.$data.'</h4>'."\n";
    else if ($part=='content')
        return '<div class="entry-content"><p>'.$data.'</p></div>'."\n";
    else if ($part=='footer')
        return '<div class="entry-footer">'.$data.'</div>'."\n";
    else if ($part=='entry')
        return '<div class="entry">'.$data.'</div>'."\n";
}
```

It works, but this code is very simple so I feel like it could be shortened. Any suggestions?

BTW. Don't post about sql injection holes. I already whitelisted table column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a switch case control structure would get you rid of these `elseif ($part ==  )`statements.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possible solution:

```
function makeEntry($part,$data)
{
    $results = array( 'title' => '<h3 class="entry-header">'.$data.'</h3>'."\n",
                      'stitle' => '<h4 class="entry-stitle">'.$data.'</h4>'."\n",
                      //etc etc....
                     );
    return $results[$part];
}
```

Comment: you've assigned the same `$data` to all array items

Comment: Yes... what's the problem with that?